# Best method to query alpha vantage api for 500 plus stock tickers - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, alpha-vantage

Still learning javascript - but I am wondering what is the best way to obtain EOD from alpha vantage api for 500 or more symbols without hitting the api too many times per second.  I have looked at code to download one symbol's info at a time, but I am trying to understand the best way to loop through multiple stocks per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is rate limited to 5 calls per minute. It will take 100 minutes to get 500 tickers.

They also limit you to 500 API calls per day, so you can only do this once per day.

You may be able to hit it harder if you pay for a subscription.